# Lightning Test Service - can you call actions directly or do they have to be wrapped in aura:method first?

Tags: lightning-testing-service

Looking in couple of examples, I can't seem find a way to call actions and action helpers directly. Is that not supported?

**Edit**: I think it's not possible, [here's a similar issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/31) (test click of a lightning:button).

**Edit 2**: Found another [issue on Github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/LightningTestingService/issues/22) that explains that you cannot.

Comment: No it's not. That's not how the lightning components framework was designed to work. Indeed you can call aura:method. However, the best way to communicate between components is to use events.

Comment: @MartinLezer I think you missed my point entirely.

Comment: Yes I did entirely...